# How can I make emacsclient use an existing window in the current frame?

Tags: window, debugging, microsoft-windows, frames, emacsclient

I'm on MS Windows, if that makes a difference.

My desired behavior:

1. There is only *one* frame visible at any time.
2. Visiting a file should use an existing window in that frame.

(This is the default behavior for Notepad++ as well as most browsers, though with tabs instead of buffers.)

To accomplish this using Emacs' client-server mode, I have this in my `.emacs`:

```
(require 'server)
(unless (server-running-p) (server-start))
```

And I have an *Edit with Emacs* context menu item that uses a registry key with this value:

`"C:\Users\FriendOfFred\emacs-26.2-x86_64\bin\emacsclientw.exe" "%1"`

That worked fine yesterday. Today, after a system restart, `emacsclientw` opens a new frame whenever I open a file from Windows Explorer or the command line, along with a message about the desktop file already being in use.

Last time I had an issue like this, as I recall, it was because the desktop file was too old, and restarting Emacs refreshed it. That doesn't seem to be the issue now.

What are some other possible causes of this issue? How can I figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

> along with a message about the desktop file already being in use

Emacsclient does not attempt to process the desktop file, so you are clearly starting a *new* instance of Emacs.

If `emacsclient` can't connect to the server, but you either passed it `-a ''` or `--alternate-editor=''` or else have the `ALTERNATE_EDITOR` environment variable set to an empty string, then it would try to start a new server and connect to that; so this is a potential explanation.

Comment: My ALTERNATE_EDITOR is set to `runemacs.exe`. When I run `emacsclientw -a ""`, it still opens a new frame, now with the message "When done with a buffer, type C-x #" - and this new frame now works as expected, i.e. all new `emacsclientw` commands target it.

Comment: Oh, well that makes sense. `ALTERNATE_EDITOR=runemacs.exe` means "If there is no server, start a new non-daemon instance of Emacs".  It will not make another attempt to connect a client in that scenario (there's no reason why it should expect that to be a valid course of action), so the behaviour you describe is exactly as expected.

Comment: That doesn't explain why emacsclient isn't connecting to the server in the first place, though...

Comment: I'm assuming that's because no server is running.  (Or if it's definitely running, make sure you haven't set a non-default `server-name`).